# Jboss 5.1 HttpOnly cookies , unable to logIn to the system

Tags: security, cookies, jboss, httponly, cookie-httponly

I added following line to my context.xml as discussed in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262416/jboss-5-use-secure-and-httponly-cookies-and-hide-jsessionid-from-url) question and now all my cookies were set to secure and httponly.

but now when i logged in to the system it throw me out and said my session got expired.

system is running on 'Http' and is there anything i missed here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using `<SessionCookie httpOnly="true" />`
instead of `<SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true"/>`